# Is it possible to have external link with jquery call?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

**Is it possible to somehow create a link with a jQuery function call?**

**For example:**
I send a client an e-mail with a link to a page. but i want to also include a jQuery function that will (just for example) pop up some div on that page (which the link was linking to) or (just another example) change some css classes on that page or so... those are just examples. the goal is to be able to fire a jQuery function after the linked page was loaded.

Comment: Are you trying to pop up a div in that email? If so that's not possible as the content of emails is highly restricted.

Comment: Do you want this pop up to display in the email or on the page after the link?

Comment: This is quite easy if you want the pop-up to happen in the browser window, but impossible in the email client itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the URL a parameter.

Example URL:

`www.ben.com/site/hello.html&popup=true;`

Catch the `&popup=true;` with a `.split()` on the & and the =, and take the parameters. Send a popup with jQuery afterwards.

Example code:

```
function popUp() {
    var href = window.location.href;
    var param = href.split('&');
    var value = param[param.length - 1].split('=');
    if (value[0] === "popup" || value[1] === "true") {
        popUpMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Idea! Thanks! although i think maybe it would be easier to fetch the parameter and do the if with php...

Comment: Indeed it is! But it's entirely possible with jQuery as well!